# Unable to set the displayName on a relationship

Tags: azure-digital-twins

I am trying to understand and set the displayName on a relationship.

My mode is a car, that has multiple tires:

```
{
    "@id": "dtmi:kevinsay:vehicle;1",
    "@type": "Interface",
    "displayName": "Vehicle",
    "contents": [
        {
            "@type": "Relationship",
            "name": "tires",
            "maxMultiplicity": 5,
            "displayName": "string"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Property",
            "name": "Model",
            "schema": "string"
        }
    ],
    "@context": "dtmi:dtdl:context;2"
}
```

and I have a tire

```
{
    "@id": "dtmi:kevinsay:Tire;1",
    "@type": "Interface",
    "displayName": "Tire",
    "contents": [
      {
        "@type": "Relationship",
        "name": "tpms"
      },
      {
        "@type": "Property",
        "name": "Manufacturer",
        "schema": "string"
      }
    ],
    "@context": "dtmi:dtdl:context;2"
}
```

I easily create a car and a tire:

```
az dt twin create --dt-name kevinsay --dtmi "dtmi:kevinsay:vehicle;1" --twin-id "Lincoln" --properties '{"Model":"Continential"}'
az dt twin create --dt-name kevinsay --dtmi "dtmi:kevinsay:Tire;1" --twin-id "lincoln1" --properties '{"Manufacturer": "Goodyear"}'
```

The challenge is building the relationship of the tire to the car trying to specify the displayName.

This works:

```
az dt twin relationship create --dt-name kevinsay --relationship-id leftFront --relationship tires --twin-id Lincoln --target lincoln1
```

but this will not:

```
az dt twin relationship create --dt-name kevinsay --relationship-id leftFront --relationship tires --twin-id Lincoln --target lincoln1 -p '{"displayName": "leftFront"}'
```

I get the error message:

[image]

And Digital Twin explorer shows the displayName on the tires relationship:

[image]

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

After much research, I found that I was asking the wrong question.  Instead of trying to set a displayName -- something that the relationship object did not have, I had to set the relationship-id, which was controlled by the '--relationship-id' flag.